# Working around a Segmentation Fault for reading Files in C

Tags: c, file, console, memory-management

I am getting a segmentation fault on the below snippet, only when I go above a text file in the range of 80-100kb. It will read smaller files of text but otherwise `segmentation 11`.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE* file;
    if (argc != 2 || (file = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Invalid command\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int capacity = 5;
    char* buffer = malloc(capacity);
    int length = 0;

    char ch;
    while ((ch = getc(file)) != EOF) {
        if (length >= capacity)
            capacity *= 2;
        buffer = realloc(buffer, capacity);
        buffer[length++] = ch;
    }
    buffer[capacity] = '\0';

    printf("%d\n", length);
    printf("%s", buffer);
    free(buffer);
    fclose(file);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

What type of problems could I be overlooking and how can I improve this code to more efficiently achieve what I am trying to get out of it (which is to read an unknown size of text from a file and output it as a string, also dynamically allocating memory by doubling array size)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides not checking the return code as @CiaPan described, there's another problem, `char ch;` is incorrect as `EOF` is not representable by `char`, it's being converted from `0xffffffff` to `0xff` and might cause an early exit if the file happens to contain the byte `0xff`.

Here's the fixed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE* file;
    if (argc != 2 || (file = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Invalid command\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int capacity = 5;
    char* buffer = malloc(capacity);
    if (!buffer) {
        perror("malloc()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int length = 0;
    int ch;
    while ((ch = getc(file)) != EOF) {
        if (length >= capacity)
            capacity *= 2;

        buffer = realloc(buffer, capacity);
        if (!buffer) {
          perror("realloc()");
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }        

        buffer[length++] = ch;
    }
    buffer[capacity] = '\0';

    printf("%d\n", length);
    printf("%s", buffer);
    free(buffer);
    fclose(file);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As fas as I can see you never test whether `malloc` and `realloc` return valid pointers.

IMHO, most probably you just get `NULL` from allocation routines; then using it causes UB, in this case resulting in memory access fault.

Comment: Okay, now this I am unfamiliar with, what do you mean by "test"?

Comment: @Computer: `buffer = realloc(/* stuff */); if(buffer == NULL) /* error */`. Also, your buffer string might be too large for `printf("%s", buffer)`.

Comment: @Computer As @hoffmale wrote above: use a conditional instruction `if (...) ...` to avoid using an invalid pointer, or even better, `if (...) ... else ...` to avoid using an invalid pointer and to return some informative message or status in case of error.